# Tomcat. Доступ к загруженным файлам

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring, tomcat, permissions

Есть spring проект, размещённый на сервере Ubuntu, который используется для загрузки файлов. Файлы успешно загружаются, но вот получить к ним доступ по ссылке не получается. Права, которые даются файлу при загрузке: 640
Пытался изменить права доступа к папке, но безуспешно. Что надо сделать и как это сделать, чтобы можно было получить загруженный файл по ссылке?

**Код загрузки файла:**

```java
File convertedFile = new File("/home/admin/web/домен/public_html/users_files/" + Objects.requireNonNull(file.getOriginalFilename()));
try {
    convertedFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(convertedFile);
    fileOutputStream.write(file.getBytes());
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вот тут посмотреть: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1812356/3212712

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Под каким пользователем `tomcat` запущен - под тем и файлы записаны будут. Права к папке `!=` права к файлам. Если `tomcat` запущен под пользователем `tomcat`, то и доступ к файлам будет только у него.

`640` (`-rw-r-----`) - у пользователя `tomcat` есть право на чтение и изменение, у его группы только на чтение, у остальных никаких прав нет.

`644` (`-rw-r--r--`) - у пользователя `tomcat` есть право на чтение и изменение, у его группы только на чтение, у остальных есть только право на чтение.

---

При загрузке файла в коде `java` можно добавить право на чтение для всех пользователей методом [setReadable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setReadable(boolean,%20boolean)):

```java
file.setReadable(true, false);
```

---

Изменить права доступа к уже загруженным файлам в каталоге можно из ОС командой [chmod](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod):

```
sudo chmod 644 -Rv "/home/admin/web/домен/public_html/users_files/"
```

- `-R` (`--recursive`) - рекурсивно
- `-v` (`--verbose`) - показывать изменения

---

Посмотреть права доступа к файлам в текущем каталоге можно из ОС командой [ls](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ls):

```
ls -l
```